# SwiftUI - show view during Digital Crown rotation

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm looking to show `Text` when scrolling but hide the text when not scrolling using `digitalCrownRotation` (like the indicator shown when scrolling). Currently it's only working one way when I scroll and doesn't work at too well, would this be possible to accomplish?

```swift
extension View {
    func hidden(_ shouldHide: Bool) -> some View {
        opacity(shouldHide ? 0 : 1)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date: Date = Date()
    @State var scroll: Double = 0.0
    @State var previous: Double = 0.0
    @State var scrolling: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(date.dateFormat("E, d MMM"))")
                .focusable(true)
                .hidden(!scrolling)
                .digitalCrownRotation($scroll, from: 0, through: 365, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
                .onChange(of: scroll) { value in
                    scrolling = (value > previous)
                    previous = value
                    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: Int(value), to: Date())!
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.date = Date()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `scrolling = value != previous`

Comment: @TamásSengel doesn't work for me, it has to be bidirectional so up and down for the `digitalCrownRotation`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show your view while user scrolls and hide when he ended doing so.

I suggest you using `.debounce` from Combine. What it does it waits for some time (1 sec in my example, should be fine for you) after each new value passed, and only pass it if no new value was sent during this time.

So in this case it'll wait 1 sec after last crown touch before hiding the view:

```
@State var date: Date = Date()
@State var scroll: Double = 0.0
@State var scrolling: Bool = false

private let relay = PassthroughSubject<Double, Never>()
private let debouncedPublisher: AnyPublisher<Double, Never>

init() {
    debouncedPublisher = relay
        .removeDuplicates()
        .debounce(for: 1, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(date)")
            .focusable(true)
            .opacity(scrolling ? 1 : 0)
            .digitalCrownRotation($scroll, from: 0, through: 365, by: 1, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
            .onChange(of: scroll) { value in
                withAnimation {
                    scrolling = true
                }
                relay.send(value)
                date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: Int(value), to: Date())!
            }
            .onReceive(
                debouncedPublisher,
                perform: { value in
                    withAnimation {
                        scrolling = false
                    }
                }
            )
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.date = Date()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Easily implemented! Thanks for showing me `debounce`!! Works perfect :D